# TwitterSDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Is there any SDK for Twitter.like Facebook ?
I Need to create login into MyApp with Twitter or Facebook.I got SDK for Facebook and completed.but now I am searching Twitter SDK for iOS.is there any or alternatives ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ACAccountStore` if you want to integrate with the Twitter and Facebook accounts linked to the device (via the Settings app).

Or you could look at [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) which offers to manage the login (both verification and the UI) and can also be used for user data storage.

Or you can use one of the libraries [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Comment: Thanks Wain..i will check it now

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

Explains everything easily on how to integrate plus + perform request.

> Twitter.framework is provided by Apple from iOS 5.0

Comment: Thanks Dante..i will check it now

Answer (score 0):

[image]

They have given this framework.Here is a screen shot to help you out.
please check this tutorial,they have explained very nicely.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

Hope it will help you.